# How to hide your password while configuring yum

Tags: yum

I am trying to configure proxy in yum.conf, specifying proxy_password. I would like to hide my proxy_password. I understand that I can use read -es, but I don't want to put it in any variable also.

Please recommend.

Thanks,
Ajay.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the include facility to put the proxy_password setting in a file with protected permissions.

Comment: Not enough .. I don't want to save it anywhere .. Any idea?